# Why smoke particles go down?

Tags: gas, diffusion

Let's say in an apartment the upstairs neighbor smokes but the smoke goes down to the below neighbors. Is it a difference in temperature that causes the smoke to flow down instead of going up through the vents?

Facts:
both rooms are closed, i.e. no windows open
temperature throughout the day is 70-75F
night temperature is 59-65

Comment: Usually, smoke goes up, not down (?)

Comment: Smoke goes up because it's usually hotter than the air.  But it will quickly equilibrate though and then act like the rest of the air, more or less.

Comment: ... except that it has particles in it which are dense. This can make the smoky air denser than clean air.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't show enough previous research.

Answer (score 0):

Smoke particles form an aerosol in the air and tend to settle due to gravity, the settling rate depends on the particle density and size distribution in the smoke, air currents, and temperature.